# Как установить и настроить библиотеку tensorflow для работы в python 3.8 под Windows 10 с GPU AMD и CPU Intel?

Tags: python, tensorflow

Как установить и настроить библиотеку tensorflow для работы в python 3.8 под Windows 10 с GPU AMD и CPU Intel  ?

---

Не нашел решение под python 3.8, но нашел для 3.6 версии

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/direct3d12/gpu-tensorflow-windows?fbclid=IwAR2iMvnpc-yEMlpb9fHv6bjUgxEDbCPqp69rPk6MI5vZIl_voKQUFMu3nZg

Comment: https://github.com/ROCmSoftwarePlatform/tensorflow-upstream

Comment: Эта библиотека работает под Windows с AMD и Intel?

Comment: судя по описанию - да. Но у меня нигде нет амд видеокарт, что бы ответить на этот вопрос

Comment: Мне нужен проверенный ответ. Библиотека ROCM работает под линукс

Comment: Я думаю, Вы быстрее проверите сами. И там в библиотеке написано, что она должна работать в винде

Comment: https://www.tensorflow.org/install/gpu

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно поставить плед, который позволил мне даже на старой AMD карте обучать https://github.com/plaidml/plaidml А далее в коде типа такого:

```
import os

os.environ["KERAS_BACKEND"] = "plaidml.keras.backend"    

from keras.datasets import fashion_mnist
from keras.models import Sequential, Model
from keras.layers import Input, Concatenate, Dense, BatchNormalization, Convolution1D, Convolution2D, MaxPooling1D, MaxPooling2D, RepeatVector, Dense,   Dropout, Activation, Flatten, LeakyReLU, Conv1D, LSTM, Conv2D, MaxPooling2D, ConvLSTM2D
from keras import utils
from keras.callbacks import ModelCheckpoint, ReduceLROnPlateau, CSVLogger
from keras import regularizers
from keras.models import save_model, load_model, model_from_json
```